# How to make a div inside a div while keeping same image background

Tags: html, css

I have a image background on a first div.
Then I want to have a div (show here for convenience with orange background) and another box "above" it with comments (called "comments box").

The problem is that I DON'T want the content of the "orange-zone' to be shown UNDER it.

Here is what I have CURRENTLY :

[image]
The problem with my current code is that some content I put in the "orange zone" div DOES go under the Comment box, which is ugly.

Here is a jsfiddle for this: [http://jsfiddle.net/uu0xe2xL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/uu0xe2xL/2/) :

**HTML**

```
<body class='example-page'>

<div id="content">
  <div class="page-main-image" >
  </div>
  <!--div with orange background -->
  <div id="orange-zone">  
  </div>
  <!-- comment box -->
  <div class="comment-box comment" style="opacity: 1;">
      xxx it's cool to comment<br/>
      nice one dude
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body.example-page {
    height:100%;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 18px;
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        margin-top: 9px;
    }
}
.page-main-image {
    height: 100%;
    background: url('http://www.thedrum.com/uploads/drum_basic_article/115509/main_images/BBCb.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#orange-zone {
    position:fixed;
    top:10%; 
    left:30%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    background-color:orange;
}
.treasure{
  position: absolute;
}

.comment-box {
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  bottom:5%;
  right:5%;
}
.comment {
  position:absolute;  
}
```

**Here is what I want to achieve**.

[image]

Notice how the orange never gets under the Comment-zone BUT the background image with an island is still visible UNDER the "comment box", which is what I want to achieve).

Also I want text to be put on the orange zone and I can't put the background image in the body tag as it has to start right after the menu, so it has a  of its own.

Feel free to update this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uu0xe2xL/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the border solution sdcr made won't work for you, you can give the inner div the same background as the outer div, and set the background-position so that they both line up. EDIT: Added color layer.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#background {
    background-image: url('http://www.desktopaper.com/wp-content/uploads/tropical-island-wallpaper.jpg');
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
}

#innertext {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

#transparent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('http://www.desktopaper.com/wp-content/uploads/tropical-island-wallpaper.jpg');
    background-position: -75px -75px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
}

#colorlayer {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
    height: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epsnar2h/1/)

EDIT: Just wanted to add, you can pretty easily automate that with Javascript as well if you want.

Answer (score 6):

The main idea is using borders to create the solid background color. See the following demo and notes inline.

**[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0bh3obcj/)**

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
/* setting up background image */
.container {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/V4xzKOv.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
/* creating the borders */
.container:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: orange;
    border-width: 20px 30px 90px 190px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
}
/* positioning the text */
.container p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 45px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/* creating placeholder and floating it */
.container p:before {
    content: "";
    float: right;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Gingerbread tootsie chocolate. Cheesecake gummi bears I love caramels gummies cake oat cake tootsie roll. Ice cream sesame snaps. Biscuit gingerbread I love gummi dragée bear chocolate cheesecake.</p>
</div>
```